# What is this jet aircraft appearing in the 2019 TV Series "Black Summer"?

Tags: aircraft-identification, fighter, jet

This looks like an F-22 Raptor, but I can hardly see it:

[image]

Comment: That would be my bet too.

Comment: F-22 or F-35. My bet is on F-22.

Comment: Air intakes suggest an F22.

Comment: Of course you can hardly see it -- the F-22 is stealthy!

Answer (score 6):

If this is in fact an actual plane (or a cgi representation of one, it is most likely a F-22 Raptor.

The picture is very blurry and somewhat distorted (probably due to panning), but features fitting to F-22 are:

- Trapezoid twin rudders (F-35 has parallelogram shaped rudders)
- Rudders fairly far from each other (twin engine)
- Rudders canted outwards (rules out F-15)
- Relatively high canopy (i.e. F-35 has the canopy positioned much lower in respect to aft fuselage
- Sleek fuselage profile (i.e. F-35 has rather chubby fuselage proportions)
- Air intake rather forward (rules out F-18)

Not being familiar with the series this is from, I'm willing to bet this is not an actual plane, but cgi. The 3D -model might be totally fictious, only resembling F-22 in the manner described above.